# Django: Showing different menus for different groups

Tags: django, menu

Our site has a main area, which is accessible to everyone and displays a specific menu. We also have a second group (password protected) that sees its own menu while that section is accessed. Recently, we've decided to add a third group. This one also is password protected and will need to see its own menu while that section is accessed.

Here's the current code, which appears to change the menu based on which group is accessing the site:

```
{% menu_item as page_item %}
{% ifequal page_item.menu.name "council" %}
{% show_menu "council" "main-menu" %}
{% else %}
{% show_menu "main" "main-menu" %}
{% endifequal %}
```

I've tried inserting another ifequal for the third group to see its own menu, but that syntax apparently is not correct. I'm sure the answer is simple, but this is beyond me.

Comment: Those `show_menu` tags are not builtins, can you post them? They should be in a file called `templatetags.py`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for responding. I've searched through folders and subfolders and cannot find that file. Let me add this: we have a web development company that we work with, but I was hoping this menu thing would be an easy fix so that I could save our nonprofit a little extra money.

Comment: After a quick search, it looks like it is part of `django-cms`.

Comment: user2208853 also means that you must look into show_menu templatetag code or documentation to check if supports permission. Just to clarify.

Comment: I found a folder by the name templatetags, but not a ".py" file by that name. Inside the folder are cache.py and i18n.py.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
{% if page_item.menu.name == "council" %}
    {% show_menu "council" "main-menu" %}
{% elif page_item.menu.name == "the other group name" %}
    {% show_menu "the other group name" "main-menu" %}
{% else %}
    {% show_menu "main" "main-menu" %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What error and what is the stacktrace? If you haven't created the other group, this wouldn't work. I also don't know anything about `django-cms` so you may need to do other things like actually creating a menu for the other group. Also, I hope you replaced "the other group name" with the actual name of your other group :P

Comment: Just tried it without the "endifequal" in the code above and used "endif." No dice.

Comment: Ha. I was supposed to replace "other group name"? Just kidding. And yes, the other group, page group, and several test menu items with dummy content have been created. I have a feeling this is more complex than what I should be tinkering with and we'll have to fork over the money for a couple hours of work. The perfectionist in me hates this...

Comment: Well what was the error or did it have to do with my screwup on the tags?

Comment: When I refreshed the site, that was the error: "Unhandled Exception."